# Caffe OpenCV 3.1/Boost error when performing `make test` command

Tags: opencv, boost, caffe, ubuntu-16.04, opencv3.1

I'm trying to install `Caffe` on my Ubuntu 16.04 with GPU support (CUDA 8.0, CuDNN, OpenCV 3.1).

When I run `sudo make test` when building `Caffe`, I get the following error:

```
.....................................

CXX src/caffe/test/test_net.cpp

NVCC src/caffe/test/test_im2col_kernel.cu

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use
-Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

nvcc warning : The 'compute_20', 'sm_20', and 'sm_21' architectures are deprecated, and may be removed in a future release (Use
-Wno-deprecated-gpu-targets to suppress warning).

CXX src/gtest/gtest-all.cpp

CXX/LD -o .build_release/test/test_all.testbin src/caffe/test/test_caffe_main.cpp

.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_gradient_based_solver.o: In function `caffe::MakeTempDir(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)':

test_gradient_based_solver.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x56): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_gradient_based_solver.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x8a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' test_gradient_based_solver.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x124): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_gradient_based_solver.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5caffe11MakeTempDirEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x15a): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_hdf5_output_layer.o: In function `caffe::MakeTempFilename(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >*)': test_hdf5_output_layer.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe16MakeTempFilenameEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE[_ZN5caffe16MakeTempFilenameEPNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE]+0x1d4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' .build_release/src/caffe/test/test_db.o: In function `caffe::DBTest<caffe::TypeLevelDB>::SetUp()': test_db.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x7f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_db.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv]+0xaf): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'

test_db.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x163): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_db.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_11TypeLevelDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x19d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_db.o: In function `caffe::DBTest<caffe::TypeLMDB>::SetUp()': test_db.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x7f): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_db.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv]+0xaf): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'

test_db.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x163): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_db.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv[_ZN5caffe6DBTestINS_8TypeLMDBEE5SetUpEv]+0x19d): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' .build_release/src/caffe/test/test_upgrade_proto.o: In function `caffe::NetUpgradeTest_TestUpgradeV1LayerType_Test::TestBody()': test_upgrade_proto.cpp:(.text+0x2a21): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_upgrade_proto.cpp:(.text+0x2a5b): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' test_upgrade_proto.cpp:(.text+0x2b04): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_upgrade_proto.cpp:(.text+0x2b43): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_layer_factory.o: In function `caffe::LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<float>
>::TestBody()':

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4d9): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x513): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5c4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x603): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

.build_release/src/caffe/test/test_layer_factory.o: In function `caffe::LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_Test<caffe::CPUDevice<double>
>::TestBody()':

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4c1): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4fb): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5a4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9CPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5e3): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' .build_release/src/caffe/test/test_layer_factory.o: In function `caffe::LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<float>
>::TestBody()':

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4d9): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)' test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x513): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5c4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIfEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x603): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)' .build_release/src/caffe/test/test_layer_factory.o: In function `caffe::LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_Test<caffe::GPUDevice<double>
>::TestBody()': test_layer_factory.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4c1): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::temp_directory_path(boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x4fb): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::path::operator/=(boost::filesystem::path const&)' test_layer_factory.cpp:(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5a4): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::unique_path(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

test_layer_factory.cpp:

(.text._ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv[_ZN5caffe37LayerFactoryTest_TestCreateLayer_TestINS_9GPUDeviceIdEEE8TestBodyEv]+0x5e3): undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory(boost::filesystem::path const&, boost::system::error_code*)'

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Makefile:599: recipe for target '.build_release/test/test_all.testbin' failed

make: *** [.build_release/test/test_all.testbin] Error 1
```

---

After googling for quite a while, I've found out that it's probably the issue with OpenCV, however, I don't know how to resolve it.

I've built OpenCV 3.1 from source following [this tutorial.](https://github.com/intel/caffe/wiki/Ubuntu-16.04-or-15.10-OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide).

I use Anaconda2 with Python 2.7 and I've created the virtual environment using `conda` (which I called `deep-learning`), so when I run `python` command in my terminal and check the OpenCV version, I get the following output:

```
(deep-learning) ➜  caffe git:(master) ✗ python
Python 2.7.12 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
>>> import cv2
>>> print cv2.__version__
3.1.0
```

Also, I can run the `opencv_version` file to verify the version:

```
(deep-learning) ➜  caffe git:(master) ✗ /usr/local/bin/opencv_version 
3.1.0-dev
```

Here's my process of building `Caffe` (assuming I'm in `Caffe` root folder):

```
sudo make clean
mkdir build
cd build
sudo cmake ..
cd ..
sudo make all
sudo make test
```

All the commands run successfully except `sudo make test`, which gives the error stated above.

Here's the output of running `sudo cmake ..`:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:725 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:763 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1332 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:725 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:763 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1332 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)


CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:725 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:763 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1332 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:5 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)


-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   system
--   thread
--   filesystem
-- Found GFlags: /usr/local/include  
-- Found gflags  (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libgflags.a)
-- Found Glog: /usr/local/include  
-- Found glog    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/libglog.so)
-- Found Protobuf: /usr/local/lib/libprotobuf.so  
-- Found PROTOBUF Compiler: /usr/local/bin/protoc
-- Found HDF5: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5_hl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial/lib/libhdf5.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so (found version "1.8.16") 
-- Found LMDB: /usr/local/include  
-- Found lmdb    (include: /usr/local/include, library: /usr/local/lib/liblmdb.so)
-- Found LevelDB: /usr/include  
-- Found LevelDB (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libleveldb.so)
-- Found Snappy: /usr/include  
-- Found Snappy  (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnappy.so)
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- Found cuDNN: ver. 5.1.5 found (include: /usr/local/cuda/include, library: /usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so)
-- Added CUDA NVCC flags for: sm_30
-- OpenCV found (/usr/local/share/OpenCV)
-- Found Atlas: /usr/include  
-- Found Atlas (include: /usr/include, library: /usr/lib/libatlas.so)
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonLibs: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (found suitable version "2.7.12", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found NumPy: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (found suitable version "1.11.2", minimum required is "1.7.1") 
-- NumPy ver. 1.11.2 found (include: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)
CMake Warning at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:725 (message):
  Imported targets not available for Boost version 106200
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:763 (_Boost_COMPONENT_DEPENDENCIES)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1332 (_Boost_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES)
  cmake/Dependencies.cmake:147 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:43 (include)


-- Boost version: 1.62.0
-- Found the following Boost libraries:
--   python
-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- Found Git: /usr/bin/git (found version "2.7.4") 
-- 
-- ******************* Caffe Configuration Summary *******************
-- General:
--   Version           :   1.0.0-rc3
--   Git               :   rc3-303-g5a201dd-dirty
--   System            :   Linux
--   C++ compiler      :   /usr/bin/c++
--   Release CXX flags :   -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Debug CXX flags   :   -g -fPIC -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -Wno-uninitialized
--   Build type        :   Release
-- 
--   BUILD_SHARED_LIBS :   ON
--   BUILD_python      :   ON
--   BUILD_matlab      :   OFF
--   BUILD_docs        :   ON
--   CPU_ONLY          :   OFF
--   USE_OPENCV        :   ON
--   USE_LEVELDB       :   ON
--   USE_LMDB          :   ON
--   ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK :   OFF
-- 
-- Dependencies:
--   BLAS              :   Yes (Atlas)
--   Boost             :   Yes (ver. 1.62)
--   glog              :   Yes
--   gflags            :   Yes
--   protobuf          :   Yes (ver. 3.1.0)
--   lmdb              :   Yes (ver. 0.9.70)
--   LevelDB           :   Yes (ver. 1.18)
--   Snappy            :   Yes (ver. 1.1.3)
--   OpenCV            :   Yes (ver. 3.1.0)
--   CUDA              :   Yes (ver. 8.0)
-- 
-- NVIDIA CUDA:
--   Target GPU(s)     :   Auto
--   GPU arch(s)       :   sm_30
--   cuDNN             :   Yes (ver. 5.1.5)
-- 
-- Python:
--   Interpreter       :   /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver. 2.7.12)
--   Libraries         :   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.12)
--   NumPy             :   /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.2)
-- 
-- Documentaion:
--   Doxygen           :   No
--   config_file       :   
-- 
-- Install:
--   Install path      :   /home/denis/code/caffe/build/install
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/denis/code/caffe/build
```

In the section `Integration with Caffe` in [this OpenCV 3.1 Installation Guide for Ubuntu 16.04](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/wiki/OpenCV-3.1-Installation-Guide-on-Ubuntu-16.04#integration-with-the-caffe), it is said that I have to include `/usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/` in my `LIBRARY_DIRS` variable in `Makefile.config`. However, I don't have `3rdparty/lib/` in my `/usr/local/share/OpenCV` folder.

```
(deep-learning) ➜  caffe git:(master) ✗ ls /usr/local/share/OpenCV
haarcascades  lbpcascades  OpenCVConfig.cmake  OpenCVConfig-version.cmake  OpenCVModules.cmake  OpenCVModules-release.cmake
```

I've done all the changes to `Makefile` and `Makefile.config` that are stated in most Caffe installation guides.

In my `Makefile.config` I have this ([here's the full file](https://gist.github.com/yakovenkodenis/6346ebde3f88256f043045177f95cc42#file-makefile-config)):

```
USE_CUDNN := 1
OPENCV_VERSION := 3
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda-8.0
WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

INCLUDE_DIRS := $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/include /usr/include/hdf5/serial
LIBRARY_DIRS := $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/hdf5/serial /usr/local/share/OpenCV/3rdparty/lib/
USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1
```

And here's some of the content from `Makefile` ([full file](https://gist.github.com/yakovenkodenis/6346ebde3f88256f043045177f95cc42#file-makefile)):

```
LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf leveldb snappy \
  lmdb boost_system hdf5_hl hdf5 m \
  opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs opencv_videoio

NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)
```

---

I'm not even sure what it can be and why the error is happening. One theory is that it is [the conflict of OpenCV versions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/t4HbtQpfAls) or something (I might have installed OpenCV 2 earlier, but I don't think I have it now, and `cv.__version__` in `python` gives me `3.1.0`). Other people say it is some linking problem, though I don't understand how to resolve such issues.

---

Could you please help me to resolve my issue and install `Caffe` normally?

---

PS: I've already spent so much time trying to install `Caffe` with OpenCV 3.1 that I think I'll be happy even with OpenCV 2 (if only it works), but I'm not sure I can completely remove OpenCV 3.1 from my system, 'cause there're lots of different files connected with OpenCV 3.1 in a bunch of different folders.

Comment: This doesn't look like an OpenCV error to me! Have you installed the boost libraries correctly? This seriously looks like a boost library issue!

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu yep, I've built Boost 1.62 from sources. And, moreover, the `cmake` script identifies it correctly. Any ideas on how to resolve that?

Comment: If you are OK, try installing the boost library using apt-get and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Should I remove my 1.62 version before installing it with apt-get?

Comment: To be on the safer side, yes.

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu So, I've removed my 1.62 version and installed Boost using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev` (version 1.58), and I get the exact same error. Maybe there's something else I can do? I really can't understand why it has to be so much pain installing all this ..(

Comment: To catch one bird at a time, it would be better, if you could comment out the python include paths and python library paths and do a make to make caffe work without python. I had faced issues when many libraries were present in anaconda too but different version numbers

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu Ok, so, I've commented out the lines `PYTHON_LIB` and `PYTHON_INCLUDE` lines in my `Makefile.config`, and now I get the error when I run `sudo make all`. Here's the error: http://pastebin.com/CALyvATC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, below are the steps I've taken to resolve my issue:

1. Remove all the files connected with OpenCV
2. Remove all the files connected with Boost
3. Remove all the files connected with Caffe
4. Install Boost using `sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev`
5. Install OpenCV 3.1
6. Turn off the virtual environment
7. Exclude Anaconda2 from path and use the standard python distribution
8. Follow the official guide and continue to use the standard python
   distribution

---

Basically, I just gave up on using Anaconda and it started to work fine.